# OpenCV c++ function in python code

Tags: python, opencv

I wrote a code that uses cv2.findchessboardcorners function, but it's very slow on python, so I want to extend that function over c++, how to do that ? 
link to the openCV findchessboardcorners implementation - 
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/calib3d/src/calibinit.cpp
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/calib3d/src/checkchessboard.cpp

how can I change this line

```
ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(''''')
```

to be faster by running on C++

Comment: The python opencv module is just a set of bindings to code implemented in c++. (http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/da/d49/tutorial_py_bindings_basics.html)

Comment: Would the function be faster by providing in explicit way the number of horizontal/vertical corners and the image in which have to be searched? Like `ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(img, (7,6),None)`